# truehist function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to make two plots in the same figure using function truehist.
How to put boxplot function into truehist histogram and visualize both together?

```
box <- ggplot(n_walmart.csv,aes(x=TotalWages),color = "Yellow",ylab ="Wages")
boxplot <- box + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()
truehist(n_walmart.csv$TotalWages,nbins=20,prob = TRUE,col = 5,
     xlab = "Magnitude",
     ylab = "Frequency")
```

Comment: `par(mfrow=c(2,1))`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want create two plot side-by-side, you can use `par()` function with `mfrow` parameter. like below :

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
```

That code generate a hidden window with one row and two columns.